# Delete() an instance

Tags: python, django, model

In my view:

```
def delete_payment(request, id):
    thePayment = Payment.objects.filter(id=id)
    thePayment.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/invoices/open/')
```

In my model:

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    raise Exception('foo')
    super(Payment, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm finding that the exception doesn't get raised unless I delete the instance from within the admin view.  That is, I can't get delete() to be called properly if I use my own view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Manager.filter()` returns a `QuerySet`, not a `Model`. `QuerySet.delete()` doesn't invoke `Model.delete()` but rather operates directly on the database.